# Getting Postfix to process the mail queue on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, email, sendmail, postfix-mta

I'm in the process of getting Sendmail/Postfix setup so that I can send and test my PHP scripts when using the mail() function.

I've got to the point that when I run the mail() function in PHP, the script executes without any errors and the mail is sent to my mailq but it then does not get processed and simply times-out with a message of: Operation timed out.

An excerpt from Terminal:

```
-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
137AA96B6C2      897 Tue Mar 16 22:27:05  nobody@imac.local
(connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.93.27]: Operation timed out)
                                         myemail@gmail.com
```

Any ideas as to how I can fix this timeout issue?

Thanks,

-P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix is having trouble connecting to that mail server (74.125.93.27).  This can be caused by a firewall or sometimes ISPs filter port 25 traffic to mitigate SPAM.

The other things that can cause this are transport and/or relays being not set up correctly.

Also, you're sending from a `.local` address.  Most mail servers won't accept this as valid.